# What events will be triggered before and after _vimrc be sourced in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to use `mkview` to make a view before I sourcing my _vimrc and use `loadview` to load view once it is sourced, but I can't find the corresponding events, did any one know?

I have already added following two lines in my _vimrc, but not works for sourcing events.

```
au BufLeave _vimrc,*.* mkview
au BufRead,BufEnter _vimrc,*.* silent loadview
```

Comment: Is this for sourcing your .vimrc after an edit, when Vim is already started up? Or do you want to do something before Vim sources the .vimrc at startup?

Comment: For sourcing my .vimrc after an edit, when Vim is already started up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `BufWritePre` and `BufWritePost` will be enough.

the following lines will load the last editing view of _vimrc when the first time it is opened, when switched to its buffer from other buffers, and after _vimrc be sourced.

```
au BufLeave,BufWritePre _vimrc silent mkview
au BufRead,BufEnter,BufWritePost _vimrc silent loadview
```

and to be more automatic, add this line to your _vimrc

```
au BufWritePost _vimrc so %
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a SourcePre autocmd in the .vimrc, to run prior to sourcing the vimrc itself. To restore, just run the loadview command as the last command in the vimrc itself (probably conditional on some sentinal value/flag).

I added these lines to my vimrc (located in $HOME/vimfiles/vimrc as allowed by Vim 7.4) to test whether SourcePre works for the vimrc. It will work when you source it manually, NOT when you load Vim and it sources automatically:

```
if !exists('s:times') | let s:times = 1 | endif
augroup TEST
  au!
  au SourcePre vimrc let s:times+=1 | echomsg "sourced vimrc" s:times "times"
augroup END
```

Every time I source my vimrc with `:exec "source" $MYVIMRC` I get a message counting the number of times I've sourced it.

Comment: ```SourcePre``` doesn't work, I added this event, however, it didn't triggered when _vimrc be sourced.